# Как в CallbackQuery получить сообщение

Tags: telegram-bot, aiogram

Использую библиотеку aiogram.
Мне нужно сохранить сообщение от пользователя в переменную `massage` в функции CallbackQuery, подскажите пожалуйста как можно это сделать? Логика такая: пользователь нажимает на кнопку добавить токен, после чего ему выводит сообщение "Введите токен" он вводит токен и он сохраняется в переменой, а я потом уже передаю эту переменную в другую функцию, которая записывает эту переменную в базу данных

Вот код:

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'button1')
async def process_callback_button1(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
    await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id,
                           'Введите пожалуйста свой токен')
```

Answer (score 0):

CallbackQuery работает только с кнопками, на которые пользователь нажал. Вам нужна другая функция, обработчик для текста, который ввёл юзер. А лучше всего, используйте встроенные возможности от aiogram:

[Finite state machine](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/examples/finite_state_machine_example.html)

Или вот, [подробный туториал на русском](https://mastergroosha.github.io/telegram-tutorial-2/fsm/).